react-native-geolocation from transistorsoft
have any of you used react-native-geolocation from transistorsoft?
I need to use it to track location when app is killed BUT it doesnt seems to work as expected or how I need it to work.
My use case should be saving users location when app isnt in active state to DB using this library. If user is traveling by car, turn geolocation off to save DB writes as it not really necessary.
When user walk, I want each 25m his new location to be set to DB. If user didnt passed 25m but stoped, I want after some amount of time (5min of not moving) his location to be set to DB as well, otherwise dont do anything.
My question is, is this code written well and given library doesn't support my needs, or is my code wrong?
If its wrong, how would you implement it or what would you change?
Im pretty lost and Docs dont really help me
Thanks a lot to everyone reading this!
My code look like this
///Context start 

const UserContext = createContext<Partial<ContextProps>>({});
const useFetchUserData = () => {
  const uid = 
auth
.currentUser?.uid;
  return useQuery(
    ['userData', uid], // unique query key with dependency on uid
    async () => {
      const user = await getCurrentUser();
      return user;
    },
    {
      enabled: !!uid, // Only run query if uid exists
    }
  );
};
// Fetch all users function using React Query
const useFetchAllUsers = () => {
  return useQuery(
    'allUsers', // unique key for all users
    async () => {
      const allUsers = await getAllExistingUsers();
      return allUsers?.data?.
users 
?? [];
    }
  );
};
export const UserProvider = (props: Props) => {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState<LocationType>({
    latitude: 0,
    longitude: 0,
  });
  const [emailVerified, setEmailVerified] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [authUser, setAuthUser] = useState<null | boolean>(null);
  const [isLoadingAuth, setIsLoadingAuth] = useState(true);
  // Fetching user data and users with useQuery
  const {
    data: userData,
    isLoading: isUserLoading,
    refetch: refetchUserData,
  } = useFetchUserData();
  const {
    data: users,
    isLoading: isUsersLoading,
    refetch: fetchAllUsers,
  } = useFetchAllUsers();
  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(
auth
, u => {
      setAuthUser(!!u);
      setIsLoadingAuth(false);
      setEmailVerified(u?.emailVerified ?? false);
    });
  }, [
auth
]);

### LINES OF CORRESPONDING CODE
  useEffect(() => {
    const onLocation = BackgroundGeolocation.
onLocation
(async location => {
      const currentLocation: LocationType = {
        latitude: location.coords?.latitude,
        longitude: location.coords?.longitude,
      };
      // Set location to DB if speed is low (still) or after moving 50 meters
      if (location.coords.speed && location.coords.speed <= 4) {
        setLocation(currentLocation);
        await setUserIntoDB(currentLocation); // User is still, set location immediately
      }
    });
    const onActivityChange = BackgroundGeolocation.
onActivityChange
(event => {
      if (event.activity === 'in_vehicle') {
        BackgroundGeolocation.
stop
(); // Stops tracking if user is in vehicle
      } else {
        BackgroundGeolocation.
start
(); // Start tracking in other modes
      }
    });
    const onMotionChange = BackgroundGeolocation.
onMotionChange
(async event => {
      const { latitude, longitude } = event.location.coords;
      const currentLocation: LocationType = { latitude, longitude };
      if (!event.isMoving) {
        setLocation(currentLocation);
        await setUserIntoDB(currentLocation);
      }
    });
    BackgroundGeolocation.
ready
({
      desiredAccuracy: BackgroundGeolocation.
DESIRED_ACCURACY_HIGH
,
      distanceFilter: 25,
      stopTimeout: 3,
      debug: false,
      logLevel: BackgroundGeolocation.
LOG_LEVEL_OFF
,
      stopOnTerminate: false,
      startOnBoot: true,
      showsBackgroundLocationIndicator: true,
    }).then(state => {
      
console
.log(
        '- BackgroundGeolocation is configured and ready:',
        state.enabled
      );
    });
    return () => {
      onLocation.remove();
      onActivityChange.remove();
      onMotionChange.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (
AppState
.currentState === 'active') {
      getLocation();
    }
  }, [
AppState
.currentState]);

  useEffect(() => {
    BackgroundGeolocation.
start
();
    setLocation({ latitude: 0, longitude: 0 });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    refetchUserData(); // Refetch user data instead of direct call to fetchUserData
  }, [isLoadingAuth, 
auth
]);

  const setUserIntoDB = async (location: LocationType) => {
    const hash = geohashForLocation([location.latitude, location.longitude]);
    await setUser({ location: location, geohash: hash });
  };
  async function getLocation(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const coords: LocationType = await getCoords();
      await setUserIntoDB(coords);
      setLocation(coords);
    } catch (e) {
      
console
.error(e);
    }
  }

///Context continues

